# Could not find FragmentActivty to start

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activty with a button i would like to start a FragmentActivity using this button. 
but my problem is my Activity is unknown. I checked My AndroidManifest all my Activities are declared . you find below the Log. In this class I am using an external lib.

```
08-02 10:51:49.574: E/dalvikvm(12660): Could not find class 'edu.dartmouth.cs.actiontabs.ViewPagerActivity', referenced from method edu.dartmouth.cs.actiontabs.TestActivity$1.onClick
08-02 10:51:49.714: E/SpannableStringBuilder(12660): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu.dartmouth.cs.actiontabs.ViewPagerActivity
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660):    at edu.dartmouth.cs.actiontabs.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:28)
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17337)
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
08-02 10:51:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12660):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the declaration of my Activity in the manifest file:

```
        <activity android:name="edu.dartmouth.cs.actiontabs.ViewPagerActivity" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError: edu.dartmouth.cs.actiontabs.ViewPagerActivity`, Is the activity name mentioned in the manifest?

Comment: I restarted eclipse, then their is no probleme.